# Fermion couplings

Tags: particle-physics, weak-interaction, electroweak

We know that the absolute sign of Axial and Vector couplings of fermions cannot be measured. Could anyone help me understand which symmetry does this condition arise from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is $SU(2)_{L}$ isospin symmetry